# Codecademy exercise - How do I rotate the camera with A-Frame's inspector?

Tags: aframe

There's no need to show the code as the Codecademy exercise tries to explain how the inspector works. So basically I've learned how to make the camera start or to move in the scene. So my question isn't about moving the camera. Rather, what I want is (using the inspector) to rotate the scene in order to look up at a certain character through the ground.

Where in the element subsection can I find the coordinates of the scene? I know the camera is positioned at (0,0,0) by default and you can move around using the ASWD movement keys. Although I don't think I can see from the ground using those keys.

I hope I'm being specific enough and there's no issue with the question. I've Googled for some time but I haven't found an answer. So if an answer is out there, sorry for not having found it.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhOcb.png)

I've managed to enter into the A-Frame inspector (as I was using the default one) and drag the `<a-entity>` as I think this is the camera object. Now, how can I try and see this picture from the ground?

Thanks for editing my question. Feel free to do it. Have a nice day.

Comment: "There's no need to show the code as the exercise tries to explain you how the inspector works"—please read [ask]. Questions here must be self-contained, and sharing a [mcve] is _always_ a good idea. (Plus, we have no idea which Codeacademy exercise you're doing. Even if we didn't require questions to be self-contained, you'd have to provide a link or something.)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing [*this Codecademy exercise*](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-a-frame)?

I think you should find out where you can modify [*the `a-plane` primitive*](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/primitives/a-plane.html#parallelizing-to-the-ground). Then play around with its *`rotation`* property.

Comment: Yes I am. The lection 11/12. I will then try to do that. Thanks.